# Specifying multiple host files to mpirun

Tags: mpi

I want to run an mpi program on multiple hosts on two sites (Rennes and Nancy in this example). I would like to provide one set of arguments to hosts on site Rennes and another set to hosts on site Nancy. I am trying to do this with the following command:

```
mpirun -configfile mpi_cfg.txt
```

where mpi_cfg.txt contains:

```
-machinefile conf/rennes/workernodes.txt parallel_wan_test conf/rennes/running.cfg
-machinefile conf/nancy/workernodes.txt parallel_wan_test conf/nancy/running.cfg
```

Now the problem is that it will launch the program correctly for line corresponding to rennes. But for nancy, instead of launching at hosts on nancy, it would launch at hosts on rennes with arguments for nancy.

Could somebody please point out to me the right way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this with just this one file, I think you're stuck.. MPI is going to read the first line and then try it, regradless fo what the second line says.

You can still automate with something like this:

1) have two files, mpi_nancy_cfg.txt and mpi_rennes_cfg.txt

2) then, in bash shell

```
mpirun -configfile mpi_$(hostname -s)_cfg.txt
```